alter contents during copy to USB thumbdrive
Using the command line,I copy a significant amount of data to a USB thumb drive. At some point the copy appears complete at which time I can enter another command even though the physical thumb drive is still flashing as if it is active.  If I enter the umount command, it takes some time to complete.
There are times when I would like to begin modifying some of the files just copied to that USB thumb drive.  Do I have to wait for the umount command to complete or, can I begin changes as soon as the command prompt returns from the copy command?

When the content is copied to RAM, the system should be ready for new commands including modifying the not yet flushed content. But there is a risk that the USB system of the operating system, the computer or internally in the USB thumbdrive might get choked.
